# Pandas - Dropping DataFrame rows based on Datetime column value

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I am currently writing a script where I want to drop some rows of my pandas dataframe according to Datetime values over several years (I want to drop rows where datetime is between February and May. So, I first tried the following code:

```
game_df['Date'] = game_df[(game_df['Date'].dt.month < 2) & (game_df['Date'].dt.month > 5)]
```

It gave me the same dataframe with NaN values in the 'Date' column over this period of time. So I tried the following code in order to drop the corresponding rows:

```
game_df['Date'] = game_df[(game_df['Date'].dt.month < 2) & (game_df['Date'].dt.month > 5)].drop(game_df.columns)
```

But it raised an error like: labels [u'**Date**' u'**other_column1**' u'**other_column2**' u'**other_column3**' u'**other_column4**'] not contained in axis

Does anyone can solve this problem?

Answer (score 4):

I think you could try something like this using a list of `Timestamp`s:

If you want to exclude rows with specific dates:

```
game_df[~game_df['Date'].isin([pd.Timestamp('20150210'), pd.Timestamp('20150301')])]
```

The `~` is a `not` operator at the beginning of `game_df` in case you're not familiar with it. So it's saying to return the dataframe where the timestamps are not the two dates mentioned.

Edit:
If you want to exclude a **range** of rows between specific dates:

```
game_df[~game_df['Date'].isin(pd.date_range(start='20150210', end='20150301'))]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Does it return the dataframe without the dates or without dates between those dates (included)? Because actually you have to considers the dates I gave like a time range and I want to exclude obsevations whose 'Date' values are within this time of range (February, 10 - March, 1st).

Comment: Do you want to exclude specific days or a range of days?

Comment: Yes I want to exclude a range of days

Comment: The code in your example shows you trying to return a `game_df` where the month is not February OR day is less than 10. I was confused.  Depending on your date range, that could exclude days you want that are not in February. I updated my answer.

Comment: I made some mistakes when exposing my problem so I made changes in my original post to help you understanding my problem. I want to drop from my dataframe rows whose datetime values are between February and May (range of time).

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I've found what I was looking for with the following code:

```
game_df = game_df[(game_df['Date'].dt.month != 2) & (game_df['Date'].dt.month != 3) & (game_df['Date'].dt.month != 4)\
                      & (game_df['Date'].dt.month != 5)]
```

It is pretty ugly and I truly think it can be done with a more efficient way but it works when it comes to exclude rows whose datetime values are located in a span of time.

Comment: It seems like your initial error was because you used `&`. The same month cannot be smaller than 2 and larger than 5 at the same time. Instead of `&` try `|` operator (it is element-wise OR).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of dropping, I find query much more helpful. But you need to change arguments of course to include part of the data you want to keep.

```
df.query("Date.dt.month < 2 & Date.dt.month > 5", inplace=True)
```

if you want to use exact dates:

```
df.query("Date <= '2017-01-31' & Date >= '2017-05-01' ", inplace=True)
```